# A type incompatibility occurred while executing org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.9.2:schema: SetBase.addExcludes(string) parameter must be instance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, avro

I am getting below error when building the below code. I've also deleted whole .m2 folder and build the project again.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.9.2:schema (default) on project 01-spring-cloud-stream-bridge-avro: A type incompatibility occurred while executing org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.9.2:schema: SetBase.addExcludes(string) parameter must be instanceof java.lang.String
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.9.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-maven-plugin/1.9.2/avro-maven-plugin-1.9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.1/plexus-interpolation-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.6/plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2.1/file-management-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-compiler/1.9.2/avro-compiler-1.9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.9.2/avro-1.9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.10.2/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.19/commons-compress-1.19.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity-engine-core/2.2/velocity-engine-core-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.10.2/jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.10.2/jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.1/joda-time-2.10.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>01-spring-cloud-stream-bridge-avro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>01-spring-cloud-stream-bridge-avro</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                            <imports>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/sensors.avsc</import>
                            </imports>
                            <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <name>Confluent</name>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

sensors.avsc

```
{
  "namespace" : "com.example",
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Sensor",
  "fields" : [
    {"name":"id","type":"string"},
    {"name":"temperature", "type":"float", "default":0.0},
    {"name":"acceleration", "type":"float","default":0.0},
    {"name":"velocity","type":"float","default":0.0}
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you find the problem?